# Databricks autoloader with files contains blank rows

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I am using databricks autoloader to ingest csv into a delta table. However my csv’s have many blank rows before the table in to the file. Is there an easy way to make sure this rows are skipped ?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the autoloader options to drop records that are corrupted/missing. When specifying autoloader parameters, use DROPMALFORMED option (https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/options.html#csv-options).
It should look like this:

```
.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
```